# How can I select multiple radio buttons in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

[code in plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ohpTfYCxk)

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items.options">
    <td width="90%" ng-bind="item.value" align="center" class="align-items-center"></td>
    <td width="10%" align="center">
    <input type="radio" id="enabled{{item.name}}" name="enabled{{item.name}}" ng-model="radio.selection" ng-change="dataforAccessRight(function.fncFunctionCode,'Y')"
        ng-value="1" />
</td>
```

I want to create a menu where I can select enabled and disabled option for various items repeated using ng-repeat.

Comment: There is no working code inside the plunkr

Comment: Check out https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/radioButton

Answer (score 0):

Well honestly, the question seems pretty vague to me. what is it that you want to enable or disable? 
Let me attempt to show how you could use ng-repeat to setup radio buttons in a table.

Here's the HTML (notice that I have copied the radio button code from the question since i do not know what exactly you wish to accomplish with them):

```
 <table border=3>
  <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
    <td>{{product.id}}<input type ="radio"
                                   id = "enabled{{item.name}}"
                                   name = "enabled{{item.name}}"
                                   ng-model="radio.selection"
                                   ng-change="dataforAccessRight(function.fncFunctionCode,'Y')"
                                   ng-value="1"

                            /></td>
    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the .js code:

```
 var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []); 
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.products = [{id:1,
                        name:"Milk"},
                        {id:2,
                        name:"Bread"},
                        {id:3,
                        name:"Cheese"}];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what he's trying to ask is that he wants an universal switch that enables/disables all of the radio buttons on the ng-repeat. The problem is that Radio buttons aren't supposed to be selected all at once, so I'll use checkboxes.

Check this working example right here:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('TestController', function($scope) {
     
     $scope.items = [
      {
        label: 'Item 1',
        selected: true
      },
      {
        label: 'Item 2',
        selected: false
      },
      {
        label: 'Item 3',
        selected: false
      }
     ];
     
     this.toggleItems = function(context) {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
          var item = $scope.items[i];
          
          item.selected = (context === 'SELECT ALL');
        }
     }
     
  });
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

form {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

form label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Universal toggle</title>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="TestController as ctrl">

  <a ng-click="ctrl.toggleItems('SELECT ALL')">
    Select all
  </a>
  
  <a ng-click="ctrl.toggleItems('DESELECT ALL')">
    Deselect all
  </a>

  <form>
     <label ng-repeat="item in items">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected"> {{item.label}}
     </label>
  </form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This should do (if I understand correctly) what you are trying to achieve.